# Pyside6 respond to keyboard input

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I'm using Pyside6

I want to change what widgets show in reaction to keyboard inputs from the user.

The minimum helpful example would be just a label that shows 1-5 depending on which number key the user presses.

My attempt (nothing gets printed, so I guess this is never called and I have to attach it to something):

```py
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        print(f"Found key {key}")
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_1:
            self.selected_bin = 1
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_2:
            self.selected_bin = 2
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_3:
            self.selected_bin = 3
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_4:
            self.selected_bin = 4
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_5:
            self.selected_bin = 5
            self.set_current_bin()
        else:
            super(self).keyPressEvent(event)

    def set_current_bin(self):
        self.ui.current_bin.setText(f"Current bin: {self.selected_bin}")
```

I feel like this is super simple, but I've searched for about half an hour with no luck.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install an event filter that listens for key presses and then set the label text to the event's key text value.

Here is a working example:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label1 = QLabel("", self)
        self.label2 = QLabel("Key Pressed: ", self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.resize(100,50)
        self.eventFilter = KeyPressFilter(parent=self)
        self.installEventFilter(self.eventFilter)

class KeyPressFilter(QObject):

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            text = event.text()
            if event.modifiers():
                text = event.keyCombination().key().name.decode(encoding="utf-8")
            widget.label1.setText(text)
        return False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: @kevinlinxc  This should work

Comment: I can't get it to work. Your example works in a vacuum, but I can't integrate it. I define the class outside of my QMainWindow subclass, and put your code  in the __init__ of the QMainWindow subclass but a qevent.keypress is not found. I put a printout at the top of eventFitler and it actually seems to detect mouse movement, but not key presses

Comment: Printing out the event,s it actually seems like they are keyreleases instead of keypress for some reason

Comment: @kevinlinxc  and event filter receives all events.... that is why I check for event type at the top of the filter.  You also need to be sure that you install the event filter on the correct widget.  And yes it was designed to work in this enviornment because that is what you requested

Comment: Changing QEvent.KeyPress to KeyRelease/ShortcutOverride made this work for me, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine in PySide2 except for having to change

```py
super(self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

to

```py
super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

in your else block.

This is my test for you to test on PySide6 to see if the veriso nis the issue:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        print(f"Found key {key}")
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_1:
            self.selected_bin = 1
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_2:
            self.selected_bin = 2
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_3:
            self.selected_bin = 3
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_4:
            self.selected_bin = 4
            self.set_current_bin()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_5:
            self.selected_bin = 5
            self.set_current_bin()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
    
    def set_current_bin(self):
        self.setText(f"Current bin: {self.selected_bin}")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    import sys
    args = sys.argv
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)
    w = TestWidget("Testing")
    w.show()
   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: So I was actually trying to put this onto a QLabel that already existed, can I do that instead of making a new Widget subclass? If not, do I just have to modify the created label every time I regenerate the ui py file?

Comment: If your label is reference by `self.ui.current_bin` just use `self.ui.current_bin.setText` like you did in your example. If that doesn't work it may be because the keystroke is swallowed by another widget.